# Find if item exist in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i was following some react/express tutorials.
im confused with code below in contacts.js file

```
 if (!contact) {
 return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Contact not found" })
        }
```

**Is above code necessary ? or whats is there better way to catch if the contact doesn't exist in mongodb ?**

when i do put request from postman with invalid id for example

```
localhost:44022/api/contacts/<invalid ID>
```

the execution never reach  if (!contact) part. if i console log the catch(err) section i get something below

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "bcvbxcxc" at path "_id" for model "contact"
    at model.Query.exec (/Users/becker/Desktop/RJS/ckeeper/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4380:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (/Users/becker/Desktop/RJS/ckeeper/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4472:15)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"bcvbxcxc"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'bcvbxcxc',
  path: '_id',
  reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
      at new ObjectID (/Users/becker/Desktop/RJS/ckeeper/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:59:11)
```

contacts.js

```
router.put('/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
 const { name, email, phone, type } = req.body;
 const contactFields = {};
 if (name) contactFields.name = name;
 if (email) contactFields.email = email;
 if (phone) contactFields.phone = phone
 if (type) contactFields.type = type;
 try {
 let contact = await Contact.findById(req.params.id);

 if (!contact) {
 return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Contact not found" })
        }

//makesure contact belongs to right user
 if (contact.user.toString() != req.user.id) {
 return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Not authorized' })
        }
 contact = await Contact.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: contactFields }, { new: true })
 res.json(contact)
    }
 catch (err) {
 console.log("reached error, contact not found")
 console.error(err)
 res.status(500).send(err)
    }

});
```

Contacts.js model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ContactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 user: {
 type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 ref: 'users'
    },
 name: {
 type: String,
 required: true
    },
 email: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
    },
 phone: {
 type: String
    },
 type: {
 type: String,
 default: 'personal'
    },
 date: {
 type: Date,
 default: Date.now

    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('contact', ContactSchema)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for not executing the `if(!contact)` condition upon exception is because `catch` block will be called and further execution in the try block is halted. You should rather **wrap** each `db` call in its own `try catch` block. Something like:

```
 let contact;
 try {
   contact = await Contact.findById(req.params.id);
 } catch(err) {
   console.log('Some db operations failed due to reason', err);
   return res.status(500).json({ msg: "DB operations failed or whatever message" })
 }

 if (!contact) {
   return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Contact not found" })
 }
 

//makesure contact belongs to right user
 if (contact.user.toString() != req.user.id) {
   return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Not authorized' })
 }
 try {
 contact = await Contact.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: contactFields }, { new: true })
 return res.json(contact)
    }
 catch (err) {
  console.log("db update operations failed")
  console.error(err)
  res.status(500).send(err)
 }
```

Comment: the error message was pointing straight whole time  - `reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters` . After i gave valid 24char id the error was caught :)

Comment: @satch_boogie That's why I pointed that you should catch the `db` errors first. Since your `id` was wrong that's why it wasn't executing the `if block` right after the `findById`